# Connect php with domino server

Tags: php, lotus-domino

Any idea to connect php with domino server?

I want to allow user to login using domino account to my php app.

Answer (score 2):

You may find this article of use as it describes one way of sending a Domino log-in request directly from PHP to the Domino server:
[Building PHP-based UIs for IBM Lotus Domino](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-php/)
Alternatively, look into using Domino as an LDAP resource (this can be done), and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, enabling LDAP on the Domino server and using that to authenticate users is the way to go.